# I need repeat a script adsense every 11 outages

Tags: php, adsense

I need repeat a script adsense every 11 outages i use this code :

```
$ads="script adsense"
if($woocommerce_loop['loop'] %11 == 0) {
    echo '<h3>Advertising</h3><div class="imagewrapper"><div class="pads">'.$ads;
}
```

this code is ok if I put in $ads amazon ads or other banner but if I put in $ads the adsense script only show me the first outage other show blank box.
Any idea what i wrong?

thanx for all guys.

Comment: Can you please clarify what's adsense script is?

Comment: something like this:
 <script src = async "// pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"> </ script>
<! - pppppppppp ->
<ins class = "adsbygoogle"
      style = "display: inline-block; width: 200px; height: 200px"
      date-to-client = "ca-pub-000000000000"
      date-to-slot = "444444444"> </ ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []). push ({});
</ script>

Comment: Have you tried using developer tools on your browser and see if there are any errors on the console/network tabs?